# About a step in the construction of the Vitali set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Accept AC. Let $x,y\in[0,1] $  and define $x\sim y$ whenever $x-y$ is rational. Consider $[0,1]/\sim$. Define the set $V$ by taking a member of each equivalence class of $[0,1]/\sim$.

Now let $q$ be rational and define $V_q:=\{x+q: x\in V\}.$ How can I prove that $\cup\{V_q: q\in\mathbb{Q}\}=\mathbb{R}$? The inclusion $\subseteq$ is trivial since $V_q\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (by definition). How do I show the other inclusion?

Answer (score 2):

Let $r\in\Bbb R$ be any number so there is some $x\in V$ such that $r-x=q\in\Bbb Q$, therefore $r\in V_q$.

Comment: I am usually fond of giving out hints for questions of this sort, but I couldn't really think of a good hint which wasn't too revealing.